# How to implement a method which takes more than 15 arguements

Tags: java

I know it's not a good approach to implement a method which takes more than 3 arguments.
But I am in a situation where I need to implement a method which takes around 15-20 arguments.

Example:

```
Mymethod (salutation, firstname, lastame,  address 1, address2, address3, address4, city, state, country, subject1, subject2, subject3)
{
//Implementation here
}
```

One approach I can think of is
Create a public class info -> have multiple inner classes within (like student name, student address, student subjects), and have the getter and setter methods within those inner classes for the the parameters which I want.

Is there any other better approach?
My requirement is to create multiple records of students with just a single call.

Comment: Are you actually asking how to **avoid** implementing a method with > 3 arguments in this situation?

Comment: Because the answer to what you *are* asking is "you just do"

Comment: Why not put the common arguments to a class `model`?

Comment: Yes, the question rather was how to avoid passing more arguments to a method , but when passed with minimal parameters, it should go inside the method and set all 15 parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap all parameters in an object. Let's say ParamWrapper. Using the Builder design pattern ([here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/builder_pattern.htm)) to construct it and pass to your method. Your code should be cleaner.

```
class ParamWrapper {
   String param1;
   String param2;
   String param3;
   String param4; 
}
//implement a ParamWrapperBuilder class
//.....
```

Your main class will be:

```
ParamWrapper param = ParamWrapperBuilder.param1("param1")
                                        .param2("param2")
                                        .param3("param3")
                                        .param4("param4").build();
//this is your method which has 15 arguments, now take only 1
doSomething(param);
```

Comment: Thank you. Upvoted. I was thinking of getter and setter methods, but this approach seems even more cleaner!

Answer (score 0):

No, if your method requires 15 arguments, that means it needs 15 pieces of information.

But rule of thumb is you probably be able to refactor your method.

You can use aggregation design pattern.

For example:

```
class MyMethodParameter {
    String salutation, 
    String firstName, 
    ... 
}
```

However, it is just a cosmetic.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options from my experience:

1. You can create a XXParam class which contains all the params as properties in class:

```
    class MethodParams {
        public int param1;
        public int param2;
    }
```

2. You can use builder design pattern to build the method before execute:

```
    int result = SomeExecutor.withParam1(param1)
        .withParam2(param2)
        .withParam3(param3).execute()
```

For second option you need to implement a builder for your method and invoke the method by execute method.